# Linear independence of a set of functions

Tags: functional-analysis, independence

Let's consider a set $U =\big\{f_{t} \big\}_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$. We define elements in $U$ as following: $f_t(x) = e^{tx}$.

Our task is to show that the set $U$ is linearly independent in $C \{[a, b] \}$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $C \{[a, b] \}$ means the space of continuous functions $g: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I don't really know how to define linear independence if $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

I would appreciate any help or tips.

Comment: My guess is that it means any finite collection $\{f_{t_1},\dots,f_{t_n}\}$ is linearly independent, i.e. there do not exist $c_1,\dots,c_n$ not all 0 with $c_1f_{t_1} +\dots+c_nf_{t_n} \equiv 0$

Comment: @mathworker21 Thank you! I will use your definition and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use the fact that eigenvectors of distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent:

Define $\phi:C^1([a,b])\to C^1([a,b])$ by $f\mapsto f'.$ 
Then, note that $T=\left \{ t_1,\cdots,t_n \right \}$ is a set of $distinct$ eigenvalues of $\phi$ for $S=\left \{ e^{t_1x},\cdots,e^{t_nx} \right \}$ which says that $S$ is linearly independent.